# MySQL COUNT with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

The following query returns me the total of 2 rows instead of 1 because it happens the video to have two categories associated.

```
SELECT COUNT(video.id) AS `total`
FROM `videos` AS `video`
INNER JOIN `videos_categories` AS `video_category` ON `video_category`.`video_id` = `video`.`id`
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `category` ON `category`.`id` = `video_category`.`category_id`
WHERE video.title = 'John Mcane' OR category.description = 'Traditional'
```

The table `videos_categories`has two lines and that's the problem.

```
id | video_id | category_id
1    1          1
1    1          2
```

I can make a count to my array in PHP but that's not correct. Any ideas of how can I solve this? `Group by` didn't work.

Comment: why id is duplicate here ? Isn't it supposed to be unique?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNT(X) counts the total number of X values it comes across that are not null, COUNT(DISTINCT X) should give you what you want (assuming X is a unique field).